# Oracle procedure to kill jobs that do not complete in given time

Tags: oracle, session, plsql, oracle11g, jobs

I have created an oracle procedure to reschedule job that do not complete in a given amount of time:

```
create or replace procedure kill_stuck_jobs
as
begin     
    for x in (  
            select j.sid,
                   s.spid,
                   s.serial#,
                   j.log_user,
                   j.job,
                   j.broken,
                   j.failures,
                   j.last_date,
                   j.this_date,
                   j.next_date,
                   j.next_date - j.last_date interval,
                   j.what
                  from 
                  (select 
                  djr.SID, 
                  dj.LOG_USER,
                  dj.JOB, 
                  dj.BROKEN,
                  dj.FAILURES, 
                  dj.LAST_DATE,
                  dj.LAST_SEC,
                  dj.THIS_DATE, dj.THIS_SEC, 
                  dj.NEXT_DATE, dj.NEXT_SEC, dj.INTERVAL, dj.WHAT
                  from dba_jobs dj, dba_jobs_running djr
                  where dj.job = djr.job ) j,
                  (select p.spid, s.sid, s.serial#
                  from v$process p, v$session s
                  where p.addr = s.paddr ) s
                  where j.sid = s.sid and 
                  j.next_date+15/1440 < sysdate  
        ) loop  
         EXEC DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(x.job,TRUE);
         execute immediate 'alter system disconnect session '''|| x.sid|| ',' || x.serial# || ''' immediate';
         EXEC DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(x.job,FALSE);
         dbms_output.put_line( 'Alter session done' );             
    end loop;  
end;
```

But this procedure compiles with error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_JOB" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "DBMS_JOB" to continue.
```

[image]

- Here came the discussion on dbms_job and dbms_scheduler_job. Actually the problem here is I created materialized view using linked db but sometime the query is stuck for whole day in session with `SQL*Net more data from dblink` . I used the above procedure to kill jobs that are created while creating materialized view and I am killing the session using :

  ```
  create or replace procedure kill_stuck_refresh as 
   begin     
       for x in (  
              select username, osuser, sid, serial#, seconds_in_wait, 
              event, state, wait_class
              from v$session
              where username is not null 
                    and seconds_in_wait > 600 
                    and event = 'SQL*Net more data from dblink'  
          ) loop  
          execute immediate 'alter system disconnect session '''|| x.sid  
                       || ',' || x.serial# || ''' immediate';
          dbms_output.put_line( 'Alter session done' );             
       end loop;  
     end; -- end of kill_stuck_refresh;
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error stack all derives from the fact that your cursor is invalid.  The cause is the ORA-00942.  This can mean the table name is spelled wrong, but as you're using the data dictionary it usually points to a permissions problem, that is, the tables (or views in this case) do not exist in your scope.

Which brings us to your comment:

> "I can run the select query independently I think that mean I have
>   those priviledge. "

This suggests to me that your permissions have been granted to a role you have rights on.  We can use permissions granted through roles in SQL but cannot use them to build permanent objects such as views or stored procedures.  For this to work you need to have permissions on those views granted directly to your user.  There is no workaround, this is the way the Oracle security model works.

---

Incidentally, you should investigate why these jobs are taking too long.  I'm assuming this is a persistent problem (otherwise why are you building a stored proc to kill these jobs?). Killing jobs is a blunt instrument which wastes resources and obliterates helpful evidence.  A better idea would be to find out the underlying cause of the poor performance and fix it.  Perhaps there's a problem with blocking sessions and you need a locking strategy.  Maybe you've got soem poorly tuned SQL.  Some other job may be running at the same time and sucks up all the resources, in which case you need a decent scheduler.  Or possibly you've just got more data now - the price of success - and you need to give the jobs more time to complete.

Comment: could you please explain blocking session and locking strategy?? The SQL is tuned as it takes only 7 sec most of the time but as it's linked db sometime during morning and night while the remote system is busy it just sticks in session.

Comment: and also even SYSTEM user (the user that is created while installing oracle express) can't compile this procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `EXEC` in this context (in a stored procedure/function). It's only needed when you want to call a stored procedure from SQL (from SQL*Plus). Just call `dbms_job.broken()` directly:

```
...
DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(x.job,TRUE);
execute immediate 'alter system disconnect session '''|| x.sid|| ',' || x.serial# || ''' immediate';
DBMS_JOB.BROKEN(x.job,FALSE);
dbms_output.put_line( 'Alter session done' );
...
```

Comment: Still not compiled properly I have attached error file in sql developer. I don't know what is the issue?

Comment: Do you have access to `dba_*` and `v$*` tables? Typically only admin accounts (`SYS`, `SYSTEM`) have access to these. If you do not have access, then you will need to be granted the necessary privileges (e.g. `GRANT SELECT ON sys.v$_process TO <username>;`). It would not be wise to create and run any code under these accounts; better to have the necessary privileges (and only those) granted to a limited rights user.

Comment: You might want to use `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION <sid>, <serial#>;`. Disconnecting a session seems rather brutal; killing it would 'roll back ongoing transactions, release all session locks, and partially recover session resources".

Comment: I can run the select query independently I think that mean I have those priviledge. I changed the disconnet to kill though..but still compiled with error..

Comment: I got the same error, it's about `v$session`. Actually it is not about `v$session` because if I change the order of tables then it complains about `v$process`. I have some faint recollection about a very similar issue, but I can't remember the details. It had nothing to do with privileges. I will let you know if I can remember what the issue (and the solution) was.

Answer (score 2):

As @David Aldridge mentioned, DBMS_Scheduler is largely meant to replace DBMS_Job (starting with 10g, actually). What he didn't mention is why this would help you.

DBMS_Scheduler provides a lot more control over it's jobs, including better logging. However, most significantly for you, DBMS_Scheduler adds a `max_run_duration` parameter to the job. If a job's run-time surpasses that duration, the job is automatically ended (and probably in a more graceful fashion than killing the session). Then, as long as the `max_failures` parameter isn't set, the job will be attempted again at it's next scheduled time.

If you can migrate your current jobs to DBMS_Scheduler, you can save yourself the trouble of writing code to provide functionality that already exists.

Comment: nice explanation for beginner like me but it's materialized view that is creating the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 11g then you ought to be using DBMS_Scheduler, not DBMS_Job. Look first at migrating to the new package, and rethink your requirement in that context.

Comment: This is sensible advice but doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Indeed, but it does suggest a course of action for the questioner to follow.